# Making a position of an object fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to make `#two` fixed when scrolled between:

```
($(this).scrollTop() > 1310 && $(this).scrollTop() <9000 )
```

This is what I have tried:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1310 && $(this).scrollTop() <9000 ) {
                    $('#two').css({positon:'fixed',bottom:'100'});
                } else {
                    $('#two').css({positon:'absolute'});
                }
            });
```

But this seems to be not working..
Help?

Comment: Looks like it should work ?

Comment: It should. The recipe is missing something.

Comment: Shouldn't `100` have a unit?

Comment: @Blender - You don't need an unit.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/2ccvR/

Comment: @Blender - it should when it's quoted, but I think jQuery uses whatever the property has been previously set to, or the default px, if it's omitted. Still, the position should work ?

Comment: of course, "not working" isn't a very good description of what the problem is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `{position:'fixed', bottom:'100px'}`. If you look close you'll see that `{positon:'fixed',bottom:'100'}` contains typos.